# nfcpy python 2.7 pyinstaller

Tags: python-2.7, nfc, pyinstaller

I am working on project that reads near field communication card and identifies the card user, I am using nfcpy with python 2.7, my nfc card reader is acr122 by ACS and I am working on windows 10. The application seems to be working fine when I run the python script.  However, when I convert the python script to .exe using pyinstaller I have error "no module named acr122". Is there any specific protocol I have to follow to bundle nfcpy in exe file. Any help would be much  appreciated, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

finally, found a solution, I need to import ['nfc.clf.acr122'] as hidden-input.